# Is there a better way to implement "Custom" Business Validators?

Tags: c#, winforms, syntax, user-controls, c#-3.0

I have a user control and I want the developer who drops the user control on the winform, can tests some values before this user control does something

I want to know if my method is good and if there is a better way to do this ?

Actually in my user control, I have a collection of `List<IValidator>` which is exposed publicly, to the developer could add `IValidator` which has implemented. This interface implements only a `bool Validate()` method.

The user control have a method named `Validate()` which iterate on the `List<IValidator>` collection and calls Validate() method.

Here is the code :

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    private SqlConnection _connection;
    private List<IValidator> _validators;


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Validate();
    }

    private bool Validate()
    {
        foreach (IValidator validator in this.Validators)
        {
            validator.Validate();
        }
    }


    public List<IValidator> Validators
    {
        get { return _customValidators; }
        set { _customValidators = value; }
    }

}
```

And the code in the winform hosting the user control :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Validator val1 = new Validator();
        myUserControl1.Validators.Add(val1);
    }
}


public class Validator : IValidator 
{
    public bool Validate()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I would know if there it could be "improved" or "simplified" (without implementing an interface) with the C# 3 syntax (lambda etc.) by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Validators.ForEach(v => v.Validate());
}
```

or even:

```
button1.Click += (sender, e) => { this.Validators.ForEach(v => v.Validate()); };
```